# My python tornado code doesn't work... why

Tags: python, tornado

I have two Handler class to compare the  @tornado.web.asynchronous decorator

```
class Test1Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):  
    def get(self):  
        for i in range(1, 100000):  
            print "kill time"  
        self.write("hello")  

class Test2Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):  
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):  
        http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()  
        http.fetch("http://localhost:8005/test1", callback=self._test_callback)  
        self.write("Hello to the Tornado world! ")  

    def _test_callback(self, response): 
        print response.body
        self.write(response.body)
```

The following is the configuration code

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/test1', Test1Handler),
    (r'/test2', Test2Handler)], debug=True)
app.listen(8005)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

OK, when I `run http://localhost:8005/test1` I can see the hello after several seconds...

However when I `run http://localhost:8005/test2`, the page is just loading and loading... I should see `Hello to the Tornado world! Hello` But I can never see the last `Hello` word...

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `self.finish()` in the handler decorated as [asynchronous](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous).

> If this decorator is given, the response is not finished when the method returns. It is up to the request handler to call self.finish() to finish the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call `finish` method to finish http request when you're using [`tornado.web.asynchronous`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.2/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous) decorator.

```
def _test_callback(self, response): 
    self.write(response.body)  
    self.finish()  # <------
```